# How do I handle migrations in sqlalchemy without any framework?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have seen sqlalchemy-migrate and alembic, but I do not want to use those frameworks. How can I write the migration script? Most of the migrations as I understand revolve around altering/dropping existing tables? Additionally, I use sqlalchemy mostly at orm level than schema/core/engine level?

The reasons I wish to do-it-myself is mostly a learning purpose and understanding how django orm automatically generates a migration script?

Comment: What do you want to migrate to? The existing tables are simply wrapped by an ORM and are just tables. The "migration" you speak of is from one Object Model **to** a modified OM. If you ditch the ORM framework, there's nothing to migrate, just data sitting happily in tables.

Comment: When I say migrate, I mean how do I handle schema changes (adding/dropping columns) to my existing tables? In django, there is `python manage.py makemigrations migrate` command. I need something similar to that.

Comment: The high-level idea is following: read Object Model from DB, read Object Model from code, compare and generate migration script with differences. You can read source code of the mentioned frameworks to understand how it's implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use alembic to execute raw sql to start.  Then if you decide to try to use more alembic features you'll be all set.

For example after creating a new revision named drop nick you can execute raw sql:

```
op.execute ('ALTER TABLE users DROP COLUMN nickname')
```

This way alembic can handle the version numbers but you can, or rather have to, do all the sql manipulations manually.

Comment: The alembic versioning system just checks a single table of version id's against the files in its versions directory to decide what to upgrade.  It's easy to understand once you init the alembic dir/table and run a few blank migrations.  Recreating that part is just busy work.